# Filtering list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

New to Haskell and have a stumbling block. I'm trying to filter a list of tuples based on the first item.

```
filter (==(x,_)) lis
```

I get an illegal '_' error, but I'm not sure how I can get around it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Haskell, you cannot iterate over a tuple like you can a list.

If the tuple only has two items, you can use `fst` to retrieve the first item of the tuple and `snd` to retrieve the second item.

One way to do what I think you want to do is this approach:

```
Prelude> let lst = [(1,2), (3,4)]
Prelude> filter ((==1).fst) lst
[(1,2)]
```

Which only returns the items in the list where the first element is equal to 1; of course, you can substitute `x` where I put 1.

To be a little more specific, `(==1).fst` first applies `fst` to the element in lst, then applies `(==1)` to the result of `fst` -- technically, the dot *composes* the two functions together.

Comment: That's great, thanks. Was wondering what those .'s were doing on all the sample code!

Comment: I think the uses of (and differences between) `.` and `$` are one of the most common hurdles to beginning Haskell -- so don't worry, you aren't the only one who's had trouble with it!

Answer (score 6):

You can't give an argument with a wildcard `_` in it to the `==` operator (or to any other function). The argument needs to be a real value, not a pattern that should be matched against.

If you want to use pattern matching you could use a lambda function as you `filter` condition:

```
filter (\(a,_) -> a == x) lis
```

Also, there is the predefined function [`fst`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:fst) to extract the first element of a two-element tuple. This can be combined with `==` to do the same test:

```
filter ((== x) . fst)) lis
```